# "JSSOR touch and swipe" in windows 8 not working

Tags: internet-explorer, jssor

I am using the jssor slider library which works perfectly fine in all devices (touch and non-touch) but fails miserably with windows8.1 touch screen kiosk machine (IE11). Even the demo links they have provided in http://www.jssor.com/ is not working in touch. However in the same device, if i use mouse and drag, things are working fine.

Tried to capture the touch events by modifying the plugin, too - still no luck. Any directions / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For supporting touch event need to listen pointer and MSPointer events in windows8.1 touch screen kiosk.

/*In $AddEvent function i added below code snippet to achieve touch support in windows 8  */

```js
/*In $AddEvent function i added below code snippet to achieve touch support in windows 8  */

var pointerEnabled = navigator.pointerEnabled || navigator.msPointerEnabled;
  var pointerEvents =  [
            'pointerdown MSPointerDown',
            'pointermove MSPointerMove',
            'pointerup pointercancel MSPointerUp MSPointerCancel'
        ];

if (elmt.addEventListener) {
            if (eventName == "mousewheel") {
                elmt.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", handler, useCapture);
            }
            // we are still going to add the mousewheel -- not a mistake!
            // _This is for opera, since it uses onmousewheel but needs addEventListener.
   elmt.addEventListener(eventName, handler, useCapture);
            if(pointerEnabled)
   {
    $("body").css("-ms-touch-action", "none");
    var msEventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
    if(msEventName.indexOf("mouse") != -1 )
    {
     if(msEventName.indexOf("up") != -1 ) {
       elmt.addEventListener(pointerEvents[2], handler, useCapture);
     }
     else if(msEventName.indexOf("move") != -1 ){
      elmt.addEventListener(pointerEvents[1], handler, useCapture);
     }
     else{
      elmt.addEventListener(pointerEvents[0], handler, useCapture);
     }
     
    }
    else if(msEventName.indexOf("touch") != -1 ) {
     if(msEventName.indexOf("start") != -1 ){
       elmt.addEventListener(pointerEvents[2], handler, useCapture);
     }
     else if(msEventName.indexOf("move") != -1 ){
      elmt.addEventListener(pointerEvents[1], handler, useCapture);
     }
     else{
      elmt.addEventListener(pointerEvents[0], handler, useCapture);
     }
    }
    
   }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution -

missed to set the css property

-ms-touch-action : none

Took time to identify this, but this resolved the problem.

Comment: hi jssor, do we have any particular version where this is targeted for rollout?

Comment: This is a bug, and it has been fixed. It's not for a particular version. It's a common feature and it should be kept in all later version.